# Female detective helping to look for a missing boy book, made into a movie

Tags: identification-request

There's a female detective/police officer helping to look for a missing boy in a town. The missing boy's mother is a nurse who was suppose to pick him up after school but there was a major accident and she stayed at the hospital. The female detective falls in love with the sheriff (deputy?).
The kidnappers were friends of the family and the husband kidnapper maybe a doctor. It was also made into a movie, maybe late 90s.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please look through the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] this question to add further details. For example, about when did you read this book? What format was it in (hardcover, paperback, audiobook, e-book, etc.)? Do you remember anything about the cover? Were there illustrations? What language was it in? Any detail may help someone crack the case of the missing book :)